# How can I perform arithmetic operations in floating points using bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm Beginner in writing bash script. I'm having problem in writing a script on performing arithmetic operator on floating point.

Comment: How is this a Ubuntu question. You have made no mention of an Ubuntu version in the question.

Comment: you'll need to run a calculator program from the bash line that performs this operation and outputs the result to stdout. I can write one for you, if you want